# Footnote continuation notice

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I have a document with multiple footnotes, some of which continue from page to page. The footnote separator has been customized for both 'continues on next page' and continues from previous page.  However, on 1 particular page, the separator shows saying the footnote continues from previous page, but a brand new footnote follows.  Is there a way to edit/delete the separator on 1 particular page only? (Word 2007)

Answer (score 0):

There is actually nothing wrong with this.

The message 'Continues on next page' is what you inserted as your 'Footnote Continuation Notice'. This will be displayed at the end of the footnote if the footnote itself is too long to be displayed at the end of the same page and has to be continued on the next page.

Your message 'continues from previous page' is what you inserted in the 'Footnote Continuation Separator'. This works a little bit different, as it is shown when there is a footnote on your page that can not be added to that same page's footnotes. Thus it is added on the next page, and the next page will display this message above it's footnotes.

So in your case, fot this particular page, you probably have a reference to a footnote on the previous page that could not be displayed on that page but is 'continued' on the next one.

Comment: Honestly, no idea, it has been a year ago. I either must have read over that 'a brand new footnote follows' part or misunderstood.